# Read logs from all apps on android from within an app for android 4.2+

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat, android-permissions

I believe there have been changes to the ways apps can read logs in android post 4.2. But I wanted to know if I can read all the logs including system logs from logcat from within an app for current versions of android? If yes does it need some permission or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you rooted you cannot do this since Jelly Bean. See this [Android bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34792) and this [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/6U4A5irWang). Quote:

> The change is that third party applications can no longer get the read
>   logs permission, however every app can read the logs containing only
>   the lines *they* have written, without needing any permission.
>
> Keep in mind that access to the logs has never been part of the SDK,
>   and is still not part of the SDK.  If you are relying on it then, even
>   after this change, you run the risk of breaking in the future.  (And
>   that is partly why this got lost for documentation, it is not part of
>   the SDK, so there isn't really a place to document it, in fact
>   documenting it would kind-of make it a part of the SDK which we don't
>   want. :p)
>
> Also we really really hope that developers don't take this as license
>   to further abuse the system logs and spew increasing amounts of stuff
>   into it from their app.  Log noise has been a continual problem on
>   Android (not just for third party apps, we always struggle to ship the
>   open source platform without a lot of noise), and if things continue
>   to get worse we will probably make further changes to it to better
>   control it.

**EDIT:** if you got access to the device, then you can peek logs there or even try to grant said permission to your app:

```
adb shell pm grant <pkg> android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

but for other cases you are out of luck (unless you find a bug in the framework)

Comment: But how about system app? If device is not rooted. Does system app still able to read other apps log through logcat programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. You just need a rooted device.

Comment: Can I do it without a rooted device?

Comment: @FD_ please example on root devices)