# Getting device log as string that I can use in my Activity

Tags: android, android-logcat

Like the title says, I'd like to get the device log on which my application will be running. Let me be more clear:

- Can my app get the device log which includes the log before my application was launched? Suppose, the application starts at time 'x' but the moment it starts, I need to get the device log 'y' hours before my application started. For this, what permissions would I need to get from user?
- If the above is not possible, i.e., to get the log from before the installation or running of my app, it should be possible for my application to collect the log if user allows the app to, right?

So, while I know that such questions get downvoted for being vague, I need someone to guide me on how to start working on this. I am not asking for any code. Just some guidance on where I can find any help or how I shall start tackling this problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You sure can take almost any file on a device for example if you know the location of the file . If your app creates a log, you can't take it since it's not even created . If it is..then yes you can..i don't know if i was helpful. Also, why not to get what you want when your app starts?

Comment: Users can not grant access to logcat. Only root can access the complete log. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977145/read-logs-from-all-apps-on-android-from-within-an-app-for-android-4-2