# Android LogCat programmatically - all processes

Tags: android, logcat

Is it possible to read LogCat messages for all processes? (like in android studio when we choose 'No Filter' option)

When I execute this:

```
    File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mylog.txt");
    if (filename.exists()) {
        filename.delete();
    }

    String cmd = "logcat -f " + filename.getAbsolutePath();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

it only writes logs connected to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android version 4.1+ you cannot read logcat of other application anymore. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22127403/3134215) for reference.

To read logs of other application for version lower than 4.1

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c").waitFor();
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v long *:*");
BufferedReader reader = 
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while (true) {
    String nextLine = reader.readLine();
    if (!nextLine.contains("LogWatcher-D")) {
        Log.w("LogWatcher-D", "See: " + nextLine);
    }
}
```

You need to give `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />` permission.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259459/3134215)

To get clear idea, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977341/3134215)