# programmatically show the logcat within application of other applications

Tags: android, logcat

I need to read and filter logcat logs within my application, of others applications. I found other questions and the most useful if [Read logcat programmatically within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application).

So I tried to write my code, but the result is always the same, that is it returns the logcat logs that made until the application was started.

```
public void getLog() {
    edLog.setText("");
    Log.e("imgspa", "ciao");
    try {
        //Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d", "*:I"});
        //Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d", "B4A:I"});
        //Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d", "-v", "time", "-e", "*VFY*"});
        //Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d", "-v", "time", "*:I"});
        //Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});
        Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d", "-v", "threadtime", "*:*"});
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcat.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        sb.append("inizio");
        sb.append(separator);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(separator);
        }
        sb.append("fine");
        edLog.setText(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried different solutions but no one can help me.
I need to get the logcat, where the application name is "B4A".

Let me point out that:
- I have a rooted device
- I already added the READ_LOGS permissions

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 4.1 it's no possible to read logs of other applications.
See an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270547/is-read-logs-a-normal-or-dangerous-android-permission)

For rooted device you need to obtain the `READ_LOGS` permission manually

```
String pname = getPackageName();
String[] CMDLINE = { "su", "-c", null };
if(getPackageManager().checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_LOGS, pname) != 0) {

    try {
       
        CMDLINE[2] = String.format("pm grant %s android.permission.READ_LOGS", pname);
        java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMDLINE);
        int res = p.waitFor();
        Log.d(TAG, "exec returned: " + res);
        if (res != 0)
            throw new Exception("failed to become root");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "exec(): " + e);
      
    }

}
```

Or just try it with `.exec("su -c logcat -d")`

Comment: I read that. But I also read if I have a rooted device, it is possible. Isn't?

Comment: If device is rooted then yes

Comment: @img.simone for rooted device use command `{ "logcat", "-d", "-v", "threadtime" }`

Comment: @img.simone Did you add `READ_LOGS` permission?

Comment: @StanislavBondar yes

Answer (score 1):

As of JellyBean, you cannot access the log in logcat that was not add there by your application.
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977145/read-logs-from-all-apps-on-android-from-within-an-app-for-android-4-2)

Comment: @img.simone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127349/how-to-read-android-log-cat-progamatically-for-other-applications

Comment: how can help me this link?

Answer (score 0):

The change is that third party applications can no longer get the read logs permission, however every app can read the logs containing only the lines they have written, without needing any permission.

Unless you rooted you cannot do this since Jelly Bean. See this [Android bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36950976) and this related discussion. Quote:

img.simone For more query you have to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977145/read-logs-from-all-apps-on-android-from-within-an-app-for-android-4-2)

Hope it will help you!!